# Load a node content programmatically

Tags: 7, nodes

How can i load the user page (profile) in a block or in the body of a another page?
I tried to put a block in the user page but does not work.
Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: the user PAGE with all its associated blocks, headers, regions, markup, etc, or the user page profile NODE?

Comment: just the information of the user profile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can print the user profile using:

`<?php print render($user_profile); ?>`.

You can get specific user information by

`<?php print render($user_profile['user_picture']); ?>`

```
<?php print render($user_profile['summary']); ?>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This will only work at the theme level. I'm not sure it's what the OP asks for.